# How to add element data attribute value inside of the element html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I can`t add data from id attribute to tag
I have this:

```
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
```

I want this:

```
<div id="id1">id1</div>
<div id="id2">id2</div>
<div id="id3">id3</div>
```

I wrote this in JS:

```
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (let div of divs) {
  divs.innerHTML=div.id;
}
```

But it doesn`t work, please help me.

Comment: `divs.innerHTML` <-- wrong variable usage.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access the `innerHTML` property of an array ( `divs` ).
You need to access that property of your `div` object, which is the current div of your loop.

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (let div of divs) {
    // you had divs here
    div.innerHTML=div.id;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!) I realized my mistake